# Troubles installing Ubuntu on a flash drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, flash

I have a 128GB flash drive that I've been trying to boot Ubuntu onto. I formatted the drive to NTFS and followed these steps. It all works fine, almost. I can boot from the flash drive and it takes me to the screen asking if I want to try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, etc. No matter which option I choose, nothing happens. My monitors lose display signal and my screens remain blank for over 5 minutes (at first I thought it was normal to temporarily lose signal to displays).

I've tried using a LiveUSB install but I can't seem to get it to run via a virtualbox.
I'm fairly new to Linux, so that's why I'm using Ubuntu. I have an Nvidia GPU/Intel CPU if that helps.

Comment: What does "boot Ubuntu onto" mean? What are "these steps"?

Comment: Ultimately, NTFS is almost certainly the wrong filesystem for this. If you want to boot a live USB image, then 128 GB is a waste of space, because the whole system will take up less than 2 GB IIRC, and even if you make a live USB with persistence, the persistence file has a size limit, which I think may be 4 GB. The live USB creator pretty much wants the system to live on a FAT partition, as well. If you want to use NTFS, I think you'll need to follow the manual directions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Create_Bootable_USB_Manually

Comment: If, instead, you are trying to install Ubuntu onto the flash drive in a permanent manner, you'll need to format the drive to a filesystem that Ubuntu likes, for instance ext4.

Comment: It is entirely possible that the flash drive you are trying to use doesn't work properly.  I have encountered several like that, a couple of which were a reputable brand, perhaps Lexar.  Before you worry yourself that it might be something you are doing, I recommend you try some other media.  I routinely "install" ubuntu directly onto Patriot Rage Pro XT usb flashdrives of a mere 32g size which I find adequate for most applications.  If the use of a particular stick grows to the point it needs more room, I use CLONEZILLA to duplicate that drive onto larger media.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording. I meant that I'd like Ubuntu to be installed onto the flash drive in a permanent manner. When I meant "these steps" it was a copy/paste from another forum and the link didn't follow but it was to this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. Currently I only have the Windows 10 preview/Windows 7 on separate drives and want to treat my flash drive as a third. With these OS's, how can I format the drive to something Ubuntu "likes"?

Comment: So after some digging I am now using MiniTool Partition to format the USB drive to ext4. However, the drive no longer appears when using ext4 format and thus I cannot select it in the installer linked in the above Ubuntu-provided guide. What I need now is a program that lets Windows see the drive and name it (i.e. a letter drive like g:) when it's formatted as ext4. I believe if I can do that, I will be able to install Ubuntu on the USB drive as if the USB driver were a form of permanent media.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a clear set up only through making a full-fledged Ubuntu installation by Ubiquity, as the main Ubuntu graphical installer instead of "useless" Wubi, an ex-friendly software aiming to be used by particularly Windows XP and other old-system users. First, and the foremost, you need to prepare a "live usb", then go for the Ubiquity, and select the 128-gb flash, and make a clean installation, but DO NOT FORGET, you should install the boot loader onto your USB drive, not your computer's primary hdd or sdd. Then, I think if you select it in your boot configurations within Bios, the system should be initiated within your flash drive. I think the process is very simple and would be OK;)